# Apply a custom norm function to an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a n-dimensional array, where last axis contains vector coordinates. If I wanted a norm like the usual 2-norm, I could just apply `np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=...)`, and it would return an array with one less dimension, containing instead norms of vectors. But how do I apply an arbitrary norm function `f(x)`, where x is a coordinate vector, in same fashion? Closest thing I found was `np.apply_along_axis`, but it calls the provided function with argument being single coordinate, and it does not aggregate values in any way.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do there might be a vectorized approach. If it's not possible you can use `apply_along_axis` with a proper function that does so. Please update your question with a minimal and reliable example.

Comment: @Kasramvd I know it is not possible, it does pretty much completely different thing, I just included it as the only example of numpy applying custom function to an array.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` seems to be exactly what you need. Please clarify your question, preferably including a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [this checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for reference.

Comment: Is the function `f(x)` outside your control? My general instinct would be to simply code the norm function such that it takes a `axis` argument and make it support arbitrary dimensions. Euclidean would be `def f(x, axis): np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2, axis))`.